# What is the closest to a 'canonical' document class for something shorter than an article?

Tags: document-classes

I'm looking to write a document which is lesser in scope than a full-fledged "article" (in the document-class sense). Some characterization explaining what I mean:

- I doesn't have as many sectioning hierarchy levels as an article. Let's say that it's the equivalent of a single section within an article
- It's not very long - just a few pages; but it's not just a 1-page or 2-page affair.
- It may have short bibliography (or it may not)
- It may have figures, but no near-page-size figures
- It should have a title/subtitle/author listing area - but it shouldn't be as wide-spaced as prominent as in an article

Is there a canonical, or at least well-regarded, document class for these kinds of documents?

*Note:* If it helps you with motivation, you can think about this as a "longer note" or "shorter report" or "shorter article".

Comment: And why not use article? You do not win much by removing sections etc

Comment: I'd say that the only criterion you've listed that's *not* satisfied immediately by the `article` document class is the last one, i.e., to provide a simplified/less prominent way of displaying a title, subtitle, author(s), and date. I suppose that this criterion, in turn, could be satisfied by replacing `\title` with `\subsection*` and `\author` and `\date` with `\subsubsection*`.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm interpreting the passage "Let's say that it's the equivalent of a single section within an article" in the first requirement as implying that (a) no `\section` directives will occur and (b) any `\subsection`-level headers should be displayed less prominently than is the default for the `article` class. This could be achieved, say, by loading the `sectsty` package and issuing the instructions `\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\mdseries}` and `\counterwithout{subsection}{section}`.

Comment: @daleif: I want the defaults to be different: The font sizes, the amounts of space, perhaps other points I'm not consideing. Otherwise - why ever use article? Just use the report class always, with no chapters.

Comment: @Mico: But the title is not a subsection*, it's the title. That is problematic to have people write, plus it may mess up the PDF.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't thinking of accessibility requirements.

Comment: Have a look her, e.g. on the mini/malist classes https://ctan.org/topic/class